# Write to file if header is a 404 using Bash and Curl on Linux

Tags: bash, curl

I have a simple script that accepts 2 arguments, a URL and a log file location. Theoretically, it should capture the header status code from the curl command and if it is a 404, then append the URL to the log file. Any idea where it is failing?

```
#!/bin/bash
CMP='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'                                                        # This is the 404 Pattern
OPT=`curl --config /var/www/html/curl.cnf -s -D - "$1"  -o /dev/null | grep 404`    # Status Response
if [ $OPT = $CMP ] 
then
    echo "$1" >> "$2"                                                               # Append URL to File
fi
```

Comment: `$OPT` contains whitespaces at the end and therefore is not equal to `$CMP`. Also you have to put both variables in quotes in your comparison. Have a look at the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28743743/1337398).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is assigning the value of $CMP to $OPT, not comparing for equality.  Try the following simpler method, which checks the return code of the grep command rather than looking for the comparison string in its output:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMP='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'
if $(curl -s -I "$1" | grep "$CMP" >/dev/null 2>&1); then
    echo "$1" >> "$2"
fi
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, however the explanation is not: He _does_ compare for equality (that syntax is valid in bash for string comparison) but he forgot quotes (as both variables contain whitespaces) and `$CMP` has additional whitespace at the end that `$OPT` does not (so no match).

Comment: My bad.  You're right, '=' is a valid comparison operator in bash. Thanks for the correction and explanation of what's actually going on.